# Handling 404 error problems in the WebView Delegate in iPhone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk

I am working with WebView based application, in that I had a problem with http 404 errors when I tried to load an url. I just want to show an alert when this happens. Can you guys please suggest me that how to trigger it and is there are any delegate methods fired when this happens?. Please suggest.

Thanks in adv,
S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not check the status code for UIWebView requests. I rarely use webviews to do requests and when I do I don't care what the status codes are. I usually use NSURLConnection or ASIHTTPRequest to do requests. If you have to know the status of the http request, then do it using an NSURLRequest object and set the delegate to receive the response status code.